# How do I use PC files for an iOS app?

Tags: ios

`//How do I use PC files for an iOS app?`

I'd like to think that I'm at least somewhat (maybe a little less than) well-versed in the ways of HTML/CSS and JavaScript/jQuery. I can make a basic website and even make it interactive and immersive. However, my current issue is that I'd like to create my own (personal use) mobile app, and I don't know how to get started. I'm just looking to create my own metronome app, but how would I import files to my phone? And even then, how do I *run the app?* Are HTML and JavaScript even languages compatible with iOS apps? I'm seriously lacking in knowledge and I don't know any better place to get it than here.

Comment: What happens if you search for a tutorial on Google?

Comment: I needed something or someone to break it down further for me. I don't understand.

Answer (score 0):

The technologies that you have mentioned (HTML/CSS and JavaScript/jQuery) are used to create websites/web pages mostly.

No, you can't use them to make a mobile application.
What you can do is, Learn iOS and then:

1. Make those websites live, make an iOS application and open that website in web View.
2. Create APIs ( if required ), make the app and integrate it.
3. And the last but best for you is: Recently a technology named react Native ([Link for the language](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/))  has been created which uses javascript as the language for making iOS and Android applications.

Learning react Native would be really good for you as it is trending in the mobile development market. It would be best for you as you find yourself good in javascript already.

In all these options, to create the app you'll need a Mac Operating System, a simulator or a real iPhone.
After that, if you wish to make your app available to the public you'll have to make the app live for which you'll need a developer account.